# Using Docker and MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, docker

I have been using Docker and Kubernetes for a while now, and have set up a few databases(postgres and mysql) and services.

Now I was looking at adding a mongoDB, but it seems different when it comes to user management.
Take for example postgres:
https://hub.docker.com/_/postgres/

Immediately I can declare users with a password on setup and then connect using this. It seems the mongo image does not support this. Is there a way to simply declare users on startup and use them similar to the postgres setup? This is, without having to exec into the image, modify auth settings and restarting the mongo service.

Comment: Isn't it possible by using env variables: docker run -d -p 27017:27017 -p 28017:28017 -e MONGODB_USER="user" -e MONGODB_DATABASE="mydatabase" -e MONGODB_PASS="mypass" tutum/mongodb or isn't this what you mean?

Comment: Yes but that is a deprecated docker repo. The official one has no mention of environment variables.

Comment: I'm sorry. I see the new repo which is pretty clear about this: MongoDB does not require authentication by default, but it can be configured to do so. When you don't want to use exec you're probably able to create a own dockerfile (based on mongodb) and configure this by your self.

Comment: This just seems like the most standard thing in the world, I am surprised I cannot find a simple configurable docker command for this.